# Converting multipart polygon geometry with true curves to single parts loses true curves using ArcPy with ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, geometry, singlepart, true-curves

I ran some test code below which creates four feature classes in a test geodatabase using ArcPy geometries in ArcGIS Pro 2.9.2:

- MultiPartPolyGeom has one multipart polygon with two parts (one a 3-sided polygon and the other a 4-sided polygon)
- CircleGeom has one circular polygon which is a true curve
- IntersectGeom is the intersection of MultiPartPolyGeom and CircleGeom and is a multipart polygon with two parts - each of those parts has one side which is a true curve
- IntersectSinglePartGeom is intended to be the two parts of IntersectGeom exploded to create two single part polygons each with one side which is a true curve

---

```
import arcpy

if arcpy.Exists(r"C:\temp\test.gdb"):
    arcpy.Delete_management(r"C:\temp\test.gdb")
arcpy.CreateFileGDB_management(r"C:\temp","test")
arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\temp\test.gdb"

sr = arcpy.SpatialReference("WGS 1984")

coordLists = [[(1.1,2.4),(4.9,2.6),(3.2,7.3)],
              [(6.1,8.8),(5.2,7.6),(7.1,2.3),(9.1,5.3)]]

arrayList = []
for coordList in coordLists:
    arrayList.append(
            arcpy.Array([arcpy.Point(*coords) for coords in coordList]))
multiPartPolyGeom = arcpy.Polygon(arcpy.Array(arrayList),sr)
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(multiPartPolyGeom,"MultiPartPolyGeom")

circleCenter = arcpy.Point(5, 3)
circleCenterGeom = arcpy.PointGeometry(circleCenter,sr)
circleGeom = circleCenterGeom.buffer(3)
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(circleGeom,"CircleGeom")

intersectGeom = circleGeom.intersect(multiPartPolyGeom,4)
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(intersectGeom,"IntersectGeom")

intersectGeomList = []
for i in range(0,intersectGeom.partCount):
    intersectGeomList.append(
        arcpy.Polygon(
            arcpy.Array(intersectGeom.getPart(i)),sr))
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(intersectGeomList,"IntersectSinglePartGeom")
```

---

After running the above code I added the resultant feature classes to a Map in ArcGIS Pro 2.9.2:

[image]

Although I expected IntersectSinglePartGeom (the purple feature class) to retain the two true curves from IntersectGeom (the green feature class) they collapsed to a straight edge.

When I first wrote this code and used it at about ArcGIS Pro 2.2 the two true curves were retained.

Consequently, I plan to report this as a bug to Esri Technical Support but assuming it is a bug can anyone anyone think of a workaround which will enable me to to get my expected result of IntersectSinglePartGeom retaining the two true curves?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One easy workaround to this is to use the Multipart To Singlepart tool instead of the Array and getPart by using this code:

```
arcpy.management.MultipartToSinglepart("IntersectGeom", "IntersectGeomSinglePartTrueCurve")
```

That retained the two true curves in the output:

[image]

Alternatively, as [commented by @bixb0012](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/428481/converting-multipart-polygon-geometry-with-true-curves-to-single-parts-loses-tru/428485#comment699083_428481):

> If you want to manually alter geometries with true curves using ArcPy,
> the only option is to manipulate Esri JSON and use the
> `arcpy.Geometry.JSON` property and `arcpy.AsShape` function.  Since
> geoprocessing tools do work with true curves, the identified
> workaround [above] may actually be a better path overall.